# How to use opencv VideoCapture to read frames from a Firewire (precisely Fire-i 630c) camera

Tags: qt, opencv

I am using opencv3.4.5, and my camera is a Fire-I 630c. I am not sure if cv::VideoCapture is able to read frames from the camera. I have tried put different arguments, e.g., 0, cv::CAP_FIREWIRE, cv::CAP_IEEE1394, which all don't work for video capturing. Here below are my codes.

It seems that camera is not recognized since a debug message is not shown.

```
//This run function is to capture images from the camera and display them in two label Qt widgets. 
void videoProcessorThread::run()
{
    using namespace cv;

    VideoCapture camera(cv::CAP_FIREWIRE);  

    Mat inFrame, outFrame;
    while(camera.isOpened() /*&& !isInterruptionRequested()*/)
    {
        qDebug() << "Camera is opened ....";
        camera >> inFrame;
        if(inFrame.empty())
            continue;

        bitwise_not(inFrame, outFrame); //cv::bitwise_not

        emit inDisplay(
                    QPixmap::fromImage(
                        QImage(
                            inFrame.data,
                            inFrame.cols,
                            inFrame.rows,
                            inFrame.step,
                            QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()));

        emit outDisplay(
                    QPixmap::fromImage(
                        QImage(
                            outFrame.data,
                            outFrame.cols,
                            outFrame.rows,
                            outFrame.step,
                            QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()));
    }
}
```

The codes in mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(&processor, SIGNAL(inDisplay(QPixmap)),
            ui->inVideo, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap)));
    connect(&processor, SIGNAL(outDisplay(QPixmap)),
            ui->outVideo, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap)));
    processor.start();

}
```

Comment: Hi, please tell about your environment. Is it MS Windows or Linux? It's very important for such exotic hardware as FireWire camera. And if you work under Windows, does any software working with video (for example Skype), recognize your camera?

Comment: @VideoProcessingResearcher: I use Windows10. The camera works fine with the software that comes with the camera manufacturer, and I also can acquire images with the aid of 1394 CMU driver (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~iwan/1394/). But I cannot use OpenCV itself (without CMU driver) for that for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you work with very expensive industrial IEEE-1394-based camera. This model doesn't have a MS DirectShow-compatible driver, so it's hard to connect from OpenCV, but it has a native API from manufacturer. I'd suggest you to wrap some functions from this API with DLL, load this DLL from your OpenCV-based application and load data from your camera frame-by-frame.